# Join polygon only if they share a border

Tags: r, spatial, r-sf

I would like yo join (make a single polygon) from a group of polygon but only if they share a border. More specifically, I would like to group the polygon as I show on the image (red circles). [image: polygons to group]

Please note that I already group all the polygons by the only characteristic that I have (which give Group.1 column of the data show below) using the aggregate function.

```
data_all<-sol_prep 
aggregate(., 
            by = list(.$dscrp_n), 
            function(x) x = floor(mean(x)), 
            join = st_touches)
```

Here the polygons for one of the groups (all polygons show in the image):

```
data<-data.frame(
  stringsAsFactors = FALSE,
           Group.1 = c("Botreaux variante non calcaire loam sableux"),
                                       geometry = c("list(list(c(-72.954502, -72.9547469863982, -72.95470248, -72.95468876, -72.95473877, -72.9547483695981, -72.9547761986361, -72.9547686141566, -72.9547375, -72.9547374779729, -72.95473747, -72.954731472972, -72.9546862, -72.9546719, -72.9546217, -72.9541111, -72.9537796, -72.9534191138071, -72.9536184876125, -72.9536894, -72.9539936, -72.954502, 45.3551106, 45.355239092866, 45.35546251, 45.35556998, 45.35571498, 45.3557402801487, 45.3558137963971, 45.3558191708586, 45.3558412, 45.3558412343503, 45.35584124, 
45.355850598887, 45.3559212, 45.3559707, 45.3559391, 45.3559456, 45.355908, 45.3557070076983, 45.3550789647557, 45.3548556, 45.3548922, 45.3551106)), list(c(-72.95585498, -72.9558549892572, -72.955855, -72.955895, -72.9558991325195, -72.95592001, -72.95605124, -72.9560714217694, -72.9560803, -72.95637, -72.9564575, -72.9566341, -72.9569507, -72.9572217, -72.9571301552681, -72.95702126, -72.9568905833338, -72.9568379, -72.956453, -72.9559522, -72.9555287, -72.9550185833598, -72.9550185, -72.954693, 
-72.954116, -72.9545888, -72.9550388, -72.955062471565, -72.95509001, -72.9557456670355, -72.9557912592063, -72.9557913, -72.9558202611095, -72.95585498, 45.35643124, 45.3564312044354, 45.3564312, 45.3562775, 45.3562731525916, 45.35625124, 45.35590999, 45.3558842884778, 45.355873, 45.3559654, 45.3561548, 45.3563806, 45.356634, 45.356801, 45.3570415117448, 45.3573275, 45.3577420051864, 45.3577584, 45.3579635, 45.3582761, 45.358517, 45.3588990375706, 45.3588991, 45.3591429, 45.3594754, 45.3579813, 
45.3564175, 45.356376444667, 45.35632874, 45.3564491192474, 45.356457492508, 45.3564575, 45.3564455427518, 45.35643124)), list(c(-72.951898010855, -72.9519478, -72.9520076, -72.9527707, -72.9532924, -72.9536606837539, -72.9535226348431, -72.9533967, -72.9531448, -72.9517319, -72.9517002194925, -72.9517082678364, -72.9517108, -72.9517272150412, -72.95182964, -72.951898010855, 45.354487084142, 45.3543493, 45.3543698, 45.3546434, 45.3548079, 45.3548521980459, 45.3552927042705, 45.3556945, 45.355554, 
45.3551603, 45.3551478076863, 45.3551220742613, 45.355114, 45.3550535355782, 45.35467642, 45.354487084142)), list(c(-72.9543244, -72.953895, -72.9536902228012, -72.9534445755317, -72.9530509, -72.9520774, -72.9519059, -72.9522108619773, -72.95232052, -72.95292562, -72.9530258104258, -72.9533351, -72.9537297, -72.9540484, -72.9543244, 45.3571336, 45.358545, 45.3591265127991, 45.3598240114294, 45.3600079, 45.3603542, 45.360533, 45.3595890653697, 45.35924967, 45.35726149, 45.3569459019483, 45.3570037, 
45.3571136, 45.3571511, 45.3571336)), list(c(-72.9515816, -72.9514235, -72.9515028, -72.9514652, -72.9514167, -72.9512285, -72.9509873, -72.9508083, -72.9507681, -72.9510517, -72.9511546, -72.9515872, -72.9523405, -72.9529401, -72.9530057, -72.9524730656377, -72.9518677727211, -72.9517880268497, -72.951764072246, -72.9517552, -72.9516049, -72.9515816, 45.3601539, 45.3593432, 45.3590646, 45.3589925, 45.3587223, 45.3583884, 45.3582523, 45.3582784, 45.3582872, 45.3573966, 45.3570278, 45.3569234, 45.3569, 
45.3569299, 45.3569421, 45.3586415902157, 45.3605727284412, 45.3606558720064, 45.3606540032887, 45.3606533, 45.360379, 45.3601539)), list(c(-72.9494737, -72.9495641, -72.9500557, -72.9498389, -72.9495833, -72.9493425, -72.9493185, -72.949384, -72.9494737, 45.3537547, 45.3536471, 45.3537113, 45.3544144, 45.3542951, 45.354123, 45.3539699, 45.3537902, 45.3537547)), list(c(-72.9476237, -72.947666, -72.9477695, -72.9480365, -72.9483671, -72.9483694, -72.9478321, -72.9475468, -72.9475753, -72.9475533, 
-72.9475693, -72.9476237, 45.3563194, 45.3559056, 45.3557621, 45.3558624, 45.355999, 45.356002, 45.3577621, 45.3576598, 45.357354, 45.3569939, 45.356661, 45.3563194)), list(c(-72.9485813, -72.9486548, -72.948614, -72.9485215, -72.9485313, -72.9486576, -72.948842, -72.9486635, -72.9484489, -72.9483725, -72.9479792, -72.9478854, -72.948192838251, -72.94830612, -72.9483324994349, -72.9484147, -72.9485813, 45.356279, 45.3565943, 45.3568551, 45.3571786, 45.3574846, 45.3576202, 45.3576476, 45.3582266, 
45.3580871, 45.3580687, 45.3578149, 45.3577812, 45.3567772640725, 45.35640736, 45.3563232430847, 45.3560612, 45.356279)))",
                          NA)
   )
```

I tried a group_by function follow with a summarize but that didn't work since I don't want to join all the polygon together.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can merge overlapping polygons with `st_union()`, though that does make a multipolygon, though you can cast that back to polygons. Your data has an issue, though: most of your polygons aren't quite overlapping—you can see the gaps in your plot—so you'll need to use `st_buffer()` to add a little bit to them so they do overlap.

First, make the data a clean sf object:

```r
library(dplyr)
library(ggplot2)
library(sf)
#> Linking to GEOS 3.10.2, GDAL 3.4.2, PROJ 8.2.1; sf_use_s2() is TRUE

# string to objects
data$geometry <- lapply(parse(text = data$geometry), eval)
# objects to lists of matrices to multipolygons
data$geometry <- lapply(
    data$geometry, 
    function(x) {
        if (isTRUE(is.na(x))) NA else {
            lapply(x, function(y) {
                list(matrix(y[[1]], ncol = 2))
            }) |> 
                st_multipolygon()
        }
    }
)

data <- st_as_sf(data)
# drop row with empty geometry from NA
data <- data[!st_is_empty(data$geometry), ]
```

Now split, buffer, group and summarize with `st_union()`, then split back to polygons and plot:

```r
# split multipolygon into rows of polygons
data <- st_cast(data, "POLYGON")
#> Warning in st_cast.sf(data, "POLYGON"): repeating attributes for all
#> sub-geometries for which they may not be constant

# set crs so we can buffer with units
st_crs(data) <- "EPSG:4326"

merged <- data |> 
    st_buffer(dist = units::set_units(3, 'm')) |> 
    group_by(Group.1) |>
    summarise(geometry = st_union(geometry)) |>
    st_cast("POLYGON")
#> Warning in st_cast.sf(summarise(group_by(st_buffer(data, dist =
#> units::set_units(3, : repeating attributes for all sub-geometries for which they
#> may not be constant

merged
#> Simple feature collection with 5 features and 1 field
#> Geometry type: POLYGON
#> Dimension:     XY
#> Bounding box:  xmin: -72.95728 ymin: 45.35362 xmax: -72.9475 ymax: 45.3607
#> Geodetic CRS:  WGS 84
#> # A tibble: 5 × 2
#>   Group.1                                                               geometry
#>   <chr>                                                            <POLYGON [°]>
#> 1 Botreaux variante non calcaire loam sableux ((-72.95396 45.35486, -72.9539 45…
#> 2 Botreaux variante non calcaire loam sableux ((-72.95603 45.35586, -72.95599 4…
#> 3 Botreaux variante non calcaire loam sableux ((-72.94801 45.35789, -72.94802 4…
#> 4 Botreaux variante non calcaire loam sableux ((-72.95164 45.36057, -72.95166 4…
#> 5 Botreaux variante non calcaire loam sableux ((-72.94959 45.35362, -72.94958 4…

ggplot(merged) + geom_sf()
```

[image: unioned plot]

Note these boundaries are different from yours because of the buffer—they're 3m bigger—but they're probably similar enough, depending on the use-case.

Comment: As a comment on the "these boundaries are different from yours because of the buffer—they're 3m bigger" note: you can consider applying a *negative* buffer of -3 meters as a last step of the calculation. this should lessen the impact of the buffer on stuff like polygon areas or what not...

Comment: Oh that's smart!